# UIActionsheet showinview not animating from bottom

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi I am doing a custom actionsheet in my application and I've noticed a small problem.

dismissal is ok but when doing the [actionSheet showInView:self.view],

the actionsheet animation does not start from the very bottom.

it appears from a good 200 pixels from the bottom before scrolling all the way up.

is this a known issue? i will paste my code below.

when doing a dismissal, it animates very smoothly from the top to the bottom.

Thanks in advance for any help !

```
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);
    datePickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

    [actionSheet addSubview:datePickerView];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Comment: Is `t];` a part of something?

Comment: just a type :) was in process of removing unnecessary lines to better focus on the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

Comment: If i do this, only small portion of the actionsheet is shown .

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You are adding a picker to a view you don't own - an internal apple view - and expect it to work (I had missed that). If you even get this to work, it may break in ios6, or a point release, or ios 7. If you have such a need, make your own view, animate that in - forget about trying to modify a view you don't own.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which is working fine.:

```
 UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    actionSheet.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [background setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [background setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 345, 250)];
    background.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [actionSheet addSubview:background];

    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 160, 320, 100);

    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cancelButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:21/255.0f green:117/255.0f blue:222/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cancelButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue" size: 22];

    [actionSheet addSubview: cancelButton];

    UIButton *airdropButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    airdropButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,3, 100,80);
    [airdropButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"airdrop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    airdropButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    UILabel *line=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,90,345,1)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    UIButton *messageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    messageButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,95,80,80);
    [messageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    messageButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;


    UIButton *mailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    mailButton.frame = CGRectMake(80,95,100,80);
    [mailButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    mailButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;


    UIButton *twitterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    twitterButton.frame = CGRectMake(160,95,80,80);
    [twitterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    twitterButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;

    UIButton *facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(230,95,80,80);
    [facebookButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    facebookButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;


    [actionSheet addSubview: airdropButton];
    [actionSheet addSubview:line];
    [actionSheet addSubview:messageButton];
    [actionSheet addSubview:mailButton];
    [actionSheet addSubview:facebookButton];
    [actionSheet addSubview:twitterButton];



    [actionSheet showInView:myProfileTable];
    [actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0,340,345,250)];
```

Look into this if you got any problem tell me.